# Seperate mesh into multiple ones

Tags: mesh, unity, vertex-groups

I'm a developer that is doing a little mini VR game. I will buy all my assets since Im not a skilled artist. I bought a pistol on Unity Asset store.

Problem is the main mesh called G17 in the picture below contains both the Main body, the slide and the trigger, I need to seperate these 3 into 3 meshes. You can see that there are vertex vertex groups for Slide and trigger. Can I somehow use this to separate the mesh? I'm a complete noob at blender so please a step, by step, guide :D Thanks

[image]

update: Edit mode loooks like this, pressing ctrl+l does nothing as far as i can see

[image]

Comment: I cant understand how to do it using that answer, I need more detailed explanation

Comment: Your case differs from the linked answer only with vertex groups' presence. Choose appropriate vertex group from the list, press Select button which will select adjacent vertices. Now with selection you can separate it; to do that hover over 3D Viewport, press `P` and choose *Selection* as desribed, [like in this example](http://i.imgur.com/qROsz8u.gif).

Answer (score 1):

You can manually select the faces you want to separate (or entire continuous chunks with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) then break up the meshes by pressing <kbd>P</kbd> while still in Edit mode then choosing "Selected".

Comment: Your talking to a complete blender noob here, with edit mode you mean if i press, if  i press the drop down saying Object mode in the pic above I can only have that option in the drop down

Comment: please see update of question

Comment: How can i select only the Slide and trigger vertex group?